# Matching an input value to a CSV value for sending out emails

Tags: python, csv, pyodbc, smtplib

I have tried searching for a long time online and on Stackoverflow but can't seem to find the answer I need.

I am building a Python program whereby a user inputs an ID, then it tries to match it to a row in a CSV file and, if successful, will send out certain details from a database that matches that ID (the email address is stored in the CSV file). At this stage, I can't keep all the information in one place (database for example) as I don't control that setup.

Here is the code that asks for the user input and 'gets' the information prepared from the database and initiates the email secure connection:

```
cursor=conn.cursor()
retailer_id = int(input("Enter Retailer ID: "))
cursor.execute("""SELECT Retailer, Retailer_Name, Account_ID, Password from Retailers
where Retailer = ? """, (retailer_id))

users = cursor.fetchone()
try:
    users.Account_ID == retailer_id
    print("ID exists!")
    print(users.Account_ID)
except Exception as e3:
    print(e3)
    print("No retailers with this ID exists!")
    raise
print(users.Retailer, users.Retailer_Name, users.Account_ID, users.Password)

# Create a secure connection with Gmail’s SMTP server, using the SMTP_SSL() of smtplib to
initiate a TLS-encrypted connection
port = 465 # For SSL
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "example@example.com"
print("Would you like to send emails out to contacts?")
password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")
```

Below is the code that reads the CSV and includes some error handling:

```
try:
    with open("contacts.csv") as file: # Sending Multiple Personalized Emails using a CSV
    file
         reader = csv.reader(file)
         next(reader)  # Skip header row
         missing = []
         for Retailer, Retailer_Name, Parent_Retailer, Email in reader:
             valid = True
             if not Retailer.strip():
                 missing.append("Retailer " + Retailer + " has Retailer ID missing!")
                 valid = False
             if not Retailer_Name.strip():
                 missing.append("Retailer " + Retailer + " has Retailer name missing!")
                 valid = False
             if not Parent_Retailer.strip():
                 missing.append("Retailer " + Retailer + " has Parent name missing!")
                 valid = False
             if not Email.strip():
                 missing.append("Retailer " + Retailer + " has Email missing!")
                 valid = False
             if Retailer is not retailer_id:
                 missing.append("IDs don't match!")
                 valid = False
             if valid:
                 server.sendmail(
                         sender_email,
                         Email,
                         message.as_string().format(
                             Retailer=Retailer,
                             Retailer_Name=Retailer_Name,
                             Parent_Retailer=Parent_Retailer,
                             Email=Email,
                             previous_month=previous_month,
                             year=year,
                             retailer_id=retailer_id),
                  )
          print(missing)
    print("Emails sent!")
except SMTPException as e2:
     print(e2)
except Exception as e:
     print("Emails not sent!")
     print(e)
```

The sample CSV file is:

| Retailer | Retailer_Name | Parent_Retailer | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID 1 | Retailer Name 1 | 1400 | example1@example.com |
| ID 2 | Retailer Name 2 | 1400 | example2@example.com |
| ID 3 | Retailer Name 3 | 1400 | example3@example.com |
| ID 4 | Retailer Name 4 | 1400 | example4@example.com |
| ID 5 | Retailer Name 5 | 1400 | example5@example.com |
| ID 6 | Retailer Name 6 | 1400 | example6@example.com |

The issue I am having is that when I input an ID and if the ID passes all the 'error handling', then the emails get sent to all 6 people in the CSV.

The IDs are unique in the CSV file but I think I am just overlooking something very simple here.

I have tried using the below 'error handling' statements in the block but doesn't seem to be picking it up:

```
if Retailer is not retailer_id:

if Retailer != retailer_id:
```

Really hope I have explained as much as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Retailer of type `int`?

It seems like you are comparing a `string` with an `int`, which would always return as `False` -> not triggering at all.

The solution is to either cast the string to int `int(Retailer)` or use `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` quoting as mentioned in the docs in comments below.

Comment: Hi @Mahrkeenerh. I thought that and made sure I turned the Retailer column as a 'Number' type for the cells. Unless that's incorrect and a better way to turn them the cells into an INT type?

Comment: @CalogeroSavarino csv.reader returns strings
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#:~:text=each%20row%20read%20from%20the%20csv%20file%20is%20returned%20as%20a%20list%20of%20strings.

Comment: ahhh I didn't know that. Looks like there isn't a way to convert the Retailer column into an INT type. Only Float. I guess I just need to allow the input to be a string then. Unless there is a way to convert the csv reader for a specific column as INT?

Comment: whole number comparison works for floats: `1 == 1.0` is `True`. However `1 is 1.0` is not `True`

Comment: Nice one. I'll give this a try and see if I can get it working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: just to let you know that I have managed to get it doing what I needed by concentrating on the data types! Thanks again!

Comment: in that case, please mark the answer as correct, so if someone else is also looking at the same issue, they can find a solution easier.